# How to parse the date passed as a odp.net parameter value?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using **Oracle Managed Data Access Client** for .net. I need to pass my timestamp(format : **MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM**) from the parameter and also have to convert it into oracle specific timestamp using TIME_STAMP() function. If I directly inject the values, it works. But if I pass through the parameter, I get an error. I believe, it takes the parameter as an object rather than varchar/string.

So, how can I pass my values as an OracleParameter and convert it to oracle specific timeStamp.

But this wont. This will display the data for the date but not for correct timestamp specified (I even need to compare fraction of seconds).

```
string SELECTGROUPSESSIONS = @"SELECT * FROM (
                                                SELECT Recent.sent_date, Recent.thread_id, Recent.body_string, Recent.body_text, 
                                                Recent.message_string, Recent.message_text, Recent.body_len, Recent.from_jid , 
                                                Recent.to_jid, Recent.history_flag 
                                                FROM JM Recent Left Join 
                                                (Select * from JM where sent_date > TO_TIMESTAMP(:FromHistory,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM')) Old 
                                                on (Recent.body_string=Old.body_string and 
                                                Recent.body_len=Old.body_len and Recent.from_jid=Old.from_jid and 
                                                REGEXP_REPLACE( Recent.to_jid , '([/])\w+', '') = REGEXP_REPLACE( Old.to_jid , '([/])\w+', '') 
                                                and Recent.history_flag=Old.history_flag and Old.sent_date < Recent.sent_date) 
                                                where Recent.msg_type ='g' 
                                                and Recent.body_len>0 and Recent.sent_date > TO_TIMESTAMP(:FromDate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM')  
                                                and Recent.sent_date <  TO_TIMESTAMP(:ToDate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM')
                                                and Old.sent_date is null 
                                                order by Recent.sent_date asc  
                                                ) 
                                                WHERE rownum  <= {0}";
```

For the values:

[image]

My query should look like.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
                        SELECT Recent.sent_date, Recent.thread_id, Recent.body_string, 
                        Recent.body_text, Recent.message_string, Recent.message_text, Recent.body_len, 
                        Recent.from_jid , Recent.to_jid, Recent.history_flag FROM JM Recent Left Join 
                        (Select * from JM where sent_date > 
                        TO_TIMESTAMP('02/19/2017 10:43:00:8357400 AM','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM') ) Old on 
                        (Recent.body_string=Old.body_string and Recent.body_len=Old.body_len and 
                        Recent.from_jid=Old.from_jid and 
                        REGEXP_REPLACE( Recent.to_jid , '([/])\w+', '') = REGEXP_REPLACE( Old.to_jid , '([/])\w+', '') 
                        and Recent.history_flag=Old.history_flag and Old.sent_date < Recent.sent_date) 
                        where Recent.msg_type ='g' and Recent.body_len>0 and Recent.sent_date > 
                        TO_TIMESTAMP('03/21/2017 10:43:00:8357400 AM','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM') and 
                        Recent.sent_date < TO_TIMESTAMP('03/22/2017 09:02:28:3049506 AM','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM') 
                        and Old.sent_date is null order by Recent.sent_date asc  ) WHERE rownum <= 500
```

C# Codes :

```
selectCommand = _factory.GetDbCommand(queryStatement, SqlConnection);

            selectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            using (selectCommand)
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var param in parameters)
                    {
                        selectCommand.Parameters.Add(_factory.CreateParameter(param.Key, param.Value));                           

                    }
                }

                try
                {                    

                    using (
                        var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        processReader(reader);
                    }
```

**Result:** 
Could it be due to mismatch of the date formats ?

[image]

Comment: You don't need any kind of parsing if you use parameters with the correct type.

Comment: What are those `{0}` placeholders?  These aren't valid Oracle parameter identifiers. The query should end with `WHERE rownum  <= :num', not `WHERE rownum  <= {0}`.  Are you using string manipulation to generate the query? That's guaranteed to expose you to SQL Injection attacks, or conversion errors at best

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry that was just to explain : if I directly pass the values. It would work. But if I pass the same value as oracle parameter, It doesn't. I get the data , but they are not precisely to the specified timestamp. My time stamp is in format : 02/09/2017 10:47:01:273161000 AM .

Comment: Please show us more complete C# code (the first C# code block is not valid as you do not substitute any `{..}`). And please do not provide screenshots, provide readable code and results.

Comment: There is no such thing as a timestamp format. DateTime or TimeSpan have no formats. Neither do Oracle's date types. Formats apply only to string literals. When you use parameters you pass the actual values, not the string literals. If you have to parse, you are already doing it wrong.

Comment: Just use parameters and set the values with `selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":sent_date",new DateTime(2016,4,13));`. Better yet, create the command with the parameters *once*, store it in a field and reuse it by passing a new connection and parameter values each time without clearing them, eg: `_selectCmd.Parameters[":sent_date"].Value=DateTime.Today;`. Remove all attempts to parse from your query and use the parameter names eg `Select * from JM where sent_date > :sent_date`

Comment: @Avi-B I'd suggest you create a *small* query first, to understand how queries and parameters work,eg try *only* `Select * from JM where sent_date > :sent_date` and a single DateTime parameter . Once you get this working, add the rest of the query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `AddWithValue()` is not available at Oracle Managed Data Access, you have to use `Add()` and assign value afterwards.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit which is even better. You create the command once and reuse it

Answer (score 2):

You should try to add the parameter values directly, i.e. instead of

```
string SELECTGROUPSESSIONS = "SELECT ...
... sent_date > TO_TIMESTAMP(:FromHistory,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff AM')
```

try

```
string SELECTGROUPSESSIONS = "SELECT ...
... sent_date > :FromHistory ..."

selectCommand.Parameters.Add("FromHistory", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = {the C# DateTime value};
```

Comment: I tried your method and also several others but I have no idea why its not working. Like in the picture posted above, I dont get the data from the specified time. But if I directly run my query with the values in sqlPlus/developer , I get the required answer.

Comment: @Avi-B post what you *actuallly* tried and the *actual* results. Either you didn't try what is described in this answer or you executed a *different* query. Another possibility is that you switched months and days when you hard-coded the date string. Parameters aren't broken and don't suffer from format conversions